# current_predicate/1 does not work with :- dynamic?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, prolog-directive-dynamic

I have some predicates that I define using asserts in Prolog.

I am using `current_predicate/1` in order to know whether the assert has been run or not (only one value needs to be asserted).

However, `swipl` keeps complaining:

```
Warning: The predicates below are not defined. If these are defined
Warning: at runtime using assert/1, use :- dynamic Name/Arity.
Warning: 
Warning: amountOfStudentsInCourseAsserted/2, which is referenced by
```

So, I added the `:- dynamic amountOfStudentsInCourseAsserted/2`, but unfortunately, this adds the predicate to the current_predicate(Predicate).. Therefore I cannot use `current_predicate/1` anymore if I am using this dynamic naming.

Is there another predicate like `current_predicate/1`that isn't true for dynamic names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in alternative the `predicate_property/2` built-in predicate and the `number_of_clauses/1` property.

Comment: Are you sure this should work? In the manual: `Fails for foreign predicates.` and it does: `clause_property(examsListAsserted, number_of_clauses).
false`

Comment: Re-read my answer. Your comment cites a different built-in predicate and a different property.

Comment: I tried using predicate_property first, then tested clause_property. I copy pasted the wrong item. But it's still the same result unfortunately: `predicate_property(examsListAsserted, number_of_clauses).
false.` It's always false

Comment: The property is `number_of_clauses/1`, not `number_of_clauses/0`. I.e. the property have one argument, which is, as the name indicates, the number of clauses of the predicate.

Answer (score 1):

The `:- dynamic` declaration is appropriate, as it will make the symbol known in the database. Then just attempt to match (with appropriate arguments, ignored in the following sample) before asserting:

```
...
(  amountOfStudentsInCourseAsserted(_,_)
-> true
;  assert(amountOfStudentsInCourseAsserted(X,Y))
),
...
```

Comment: s(X). A tad bit safer would be `(  clause(amountOfStudentsInCourseAsserted(_,_), _) -> ...`