# In SWI Prolog, how can I prevent the interpreter from entering interactive mode during an error?

Tags: prolog

Suppose I have a broken program like this:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(verbose, silent).
:- initialization(main).

main :-
  not_valid(X),
  halt.
main :-
  halt(1).
```

When I run it, SWI-Prolog tries to recover by entering an interactive mode:

```sh
swipl ./test.pl
Warning: /home/foo/test.pl:4:
    Singleton variables: [X]
ERROR: /home/foo/test.pl:2: Initialization goal raised exception:
ERROR: main/0: Undefined procedure: not_valid/1
?-
```

How can I make it crash instead?

---

```sh
swipl --version
SWI-Prolog version 7.6.4 for amd64
```

Comment: I think the answer is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485686/current-predicate-1-does-not-work-with-dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You may wrap the call to your main procedure with [`catch/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=catch/3) and do something upon getting an error.

For example:

```
:- initialization(catch(main, Err, handle_error(Err))).

handle_error(Err):-
  writeln(Err),
  writeln('halting...'),
  halt(2).
```